# how to validate input fields on change and enable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input fields, which I want to validate directly as the user is typing

The input fields are bind to certain conditions though.

Here is the example:

```
<input type="text" data-type="inputFullName" />
<br />
<input type="text" data-type="inputEmail" />
<br />
<input type="text" data-type="inputPhone" />
<br / >
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" />
<label>Check here</label>
<br />
<button id="button1" disabled>Click</button>
```

And the JS:

```
$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
   $('#button1').prop('disabled', $('input[data-type="inputFullName"]').val() == '' || $('input[data-type="inputEmail"]').val() == '' || $('input[data-type="inputPhone"]').val() == '' || !$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
});
```

So far so good, but how can I check for:

**1)** user has entered full name (first+lastname)

**2)** email is actually an email

**3)** phonenumber is 8 numbers long

I have made an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uey1yoh/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What pattern you are looking for `first+lastname` ?

Comment: Your 3 questions have tons of duplicates in stackoverflow. **Use the search engine** and don't repeat that simple tasks for zillions.

Comment: @RayonDabre the pattern should be basic, like `My Name`, but also `my name` or  `my another name`

Comment: Have you tried [searching](https://google.com/?q=jQuery+form+validation)?

Comment: Use another field/texbox for last name and put as mandatory. It is easy for you.

Comment: It is just using many things togetherout here..Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7uey1yoh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Email validation can be done by this:
[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

phonenumber:

```
<input type="text" id="inputPhonenumber" >
```

js:

```
var phonenumber = document.getElementById("inputPhonenumber").value;
if(phonenumber.length == 8)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

These questions have been answered before. And they are not that hard to find here.